# Spring Cloud Stream and Hibernate Validator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, hibernate-validator

Recently, I've been playing with the last version of spring cloud Stream ( using its functional programming style). Although I have read the whole [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/index.html), I could not understand how could I use hibernate Validator in my function. I've read the source code and I have understood that the only resolver that could validate the payload is **SmartPayloadArgumentResolver** but it's been never selected because the parameter type is always of type message. So, I was wondering how could I use the validator in my function? here is my listener implementation.

```
@Component
public class SampleListener implements Function<Person, String>{

   @Override
   public String apply(@Valid Person person) {
       return person.getName().toUpperCase();
   }
}
```

In my example person's name has been annotated with @NotBlank but the problem is that I would get NullPointerException if instead of hibernate validator exception.

Answer (score 0):

You must do it manually, injecting a `Validator` instance into your component, then calling `validator.validate(person)`:

```java
@Component
public class SampleListener implements Function<Person, String> {

    private final Validator validator; 

    @Override
    public String apply(Person person) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> constraints = validator.validate(person);
        if (!constraints.isEmpty()) {
            // handle validation errors
        }
        return person.getName().toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649311/spring-cloud-stream-validation-functional-approach/73737777